# Get db adapter from application object in Zend Framework 1

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdo, zend-db

I am working on an application written in Zend Framework.  I want to create a stand-alone API.  I'm copying over from `public/index.php`, and here is the key code on that:

```
/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(APPLICATION_ENV, APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini');
$application->bootstrap()->run();
```

I have copied that over minus the `run()` directive, and now I'm trying to write db queries..  I've tried:

```
$application->_connection; //not declared, fails
$application->_db; //same deal
$application->select(); //same deal
```

I want to run things like:

```
$result = $application->_some_connection_object_but_where->query( .. );
```

Can you help me answer the "but where" part?  Thanks

--EDITED INFO--

Also, to answer the great response I had on this, I do have a file called `/application/Bootstrap.php` with a class called:

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
```

and this method for connection:

```
protected function _initDb()
{
    $appConfig = new Zend_Config_Ini('../application/configs/application.ini', APPLICATION_ENV);
    Zend_Registry::set('appConfig',$appConfig);

    $dbConfig = new Zend_Config_Ini('../application/configs/db.ini', APPLICATION_ENV);
    Zend_Registry::set('dbConfig',$dbConfig);
    $db = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql(array(
        'host' => $dbConfig->database->params->host,
        'username' => $dbConfig->database->params->username,
        'password' => $dbConfig->database->params->password,
        'dbname' => $dbConfig->database->params->dbname,
   ));
    $db->setFetchMode(Zend_Db::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $db->getConnection(); // force a connection... do not wait for 'lazy' connection binding later
    Zend_Registry::set('db',$db);

    Zend_Db_Table::setDefaultAdapter($db);

}
```

Comment: The answer depends on the contents of your bootstrap and config. `Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter()` might work depending on your setup.

Comment: @rjdown, that worked great.  The accepted answer also worked so it's good to know there are two approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have bootstrapped your resources in the "standard" way using references in your `./application/config/application.ini` file of the form:

```
resources.db.adapter = mysql
resources.db.params.host = localhost
// etc
```

then you should be able to get the adapter object from the `Zend_Application` object using:

```
$adapter = $application->getBootstrap()->getResource('db');
```

Then you can write your db queries against that adapter.

[Or - even better - feed that adapter into a model that encapsulates/hides the specific db-queries inside a well-defined interface whose implementations will be more testable.]

**Update**

Per request, here is an example of injecting a db-adapter into a model.

```
class Application_Model_BaseModel
{
    protected $db;

    public function __construct($db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

}

class Application_Model_Users extends Application_Model_BaseModel
{
    public function getVerifiedUsers()
    {
        $select = $this->db->select()
            ->from('users')
            ->where(array(
                'verified' => true,
            ));
        return $this->db->fetchAll($select);
    }    
}
```

Usage would then be:

```
$model = new Application_Model_Users($db);
$users = $model->getVerifiedUsers();
```

This could be probably tightened further by using `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract` as the base model, but I intentionally provided a bare-bones example to show what I mean about injecting a db adapter into a model.

Comment: David, I added to my OP so as to clarify for any future user.  Thank you for a concise answer.  Your post caused me to look at Bootstrap.php and I discovered that the commentor on my post who suggested using `$this->db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter()` also was correct.

Comment: @Oliver Williams: Of course, in the current situation, you could access the application object - from anywhere - from global scope via `$_GLOBALS['application']`. But this is undesirable in many ways. Hit me in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92921/zend-framework-zf1-zf2) if you want to talk further.

Comment: And, you note, once created, you could stash the adapter in the `Zend_Registry` instance, thereby making it accessible anywhere, which is *very* convenient. But there is an insidious downside: every static/global reference an app has increases the component linkages, making debugging and unit-testing harder.